# Proof that $P(x)=x-\frac{1}3 x^3+\frac{1}{5}x^5-\frac{1}{7}x^7+\cdots$ has radius of convergence $1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions

> Proof that
>   $P(x)=x-\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{1}{5}x^5-\frac{1}{7}x^7+\cdots$ has
>   radius of convergence $1$

First of all, I need to convert this to a series:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2k-1}(-1)^k}{1-2k}$$

(I hope this is correct so far?)

On this series, you use ratio test, count the limit and then take the reciprocal of the limit which will hopefully equal 1:

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left (\frac{x^{2(k+1)-1}(-1)^{k+1}}{1-2(k+1)}: \frac{x^{2k-1}(-1)^k}{1-2k}\right ) = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\left(x^{2k+1}(-1)^{k+1}\right)(1-2k)}{(-2k-1) (x^{2k-1}(-1)^k)}$$

$$=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{x^{2k+1}}{x^{2k-1}}\right ) \cdot \left(\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(-1)^k}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1-2k}{-2k-1}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left (x^{2k+1-2k+1} \right )\cdot\left ((-1)^{k+1-k} \right )\cdot\left (\frac{k(\frac{1}{k}-2)}{k(-2-\frac{1}{k})} \right )$$

$$=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}x^2\cdot((-1)^k)\cdot\left (\frac{\frac{1}{k}-2}{-2-\frac{1}{k}} \right )=-x^2\cdot\left(\frac{0-2}{-2-0} \right) = -x^2$$

$$R=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$

After all, I don't get 1 as result... :(

Where is my mistake? I cannot imagine it's as complicated and long as I did?

Or maybe, at the end, I ignore the $x^2$? Then result would be 1!?

Comment: When is the absolute value of $-x^2$ less than $1$?

Comment: The ratio test says "If $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|<1$, then $\sum a_n$ converges".

Comment: @JasonM Yeah and in this case it is equal to 1. But that doesn't forbid me to use ratio test, or does it? I want proof that radius of convergence is 1, not that the series is convergent.

Comment: @cnmesr The radius of convergence is the real number $R$ such that the sum converges for all $x$, $-R < x < R$.  The _interval_ of convergence is slightly larger than this: it's $-R\leq x \leq R$, but you can still use the ratio test to find $R$ (it's 1).  To show $x$ can equal $\pm R$, you need to use a different test

Comment: Alright I have used ratio test here but why I don't get 1 as radius? What's my mistake?
One note: This is no homework, it's preparation for an exam as all my other questions are.

Comment: $$\limsup_{n\to +\infty} \sqrt[n]{n}=1,$$ what else do you need?

Comment: But what does this have to do with the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the absolute value of your algebra gives $x^2$.  Since the ratio test looks for when this is $<1$, we ask ourselves when is $|x^2|<1$.  The answer is when $-1<x<1$, and if $|x|>1$ it does not converge.  This suffices to find the radius; it is $1$.

If you want the *interval* of convergence as well, then you need to test when $|x|=1$.  In particular, just test $x=1$.  Then your sum becomes $$1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\ldots$$

which must converge by the alternating series test.  Therefore, the interval of convergence is $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.

Note, the radius is the same

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean my way is correct? Or completely wrong? I'm a bit confused because I worked a lot today.

Comment: It's correct, just incomplete.

Comment: @cnmesr If my answer was helpful, please "accept" it by clicking on the checkmark under the arrows next to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understood. I should have ignored the $x$ from the beginning since this is a power series...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is the sequence of terms of this series. Then it is clear that $\lim \sup (|a_n|)^{1/n} = 1 $ so that the radius of convergence is $1$.